# How do I create a configurable product with associated products?

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise

The following code does create a configurable product, however, when I open the product in the backend, the following message appears:

when I create the configurable product and open it in the backend, I get this message: Select Configurable Attributes Only attributes with scope "Global", input type "Dropdown" and Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" are available.

```
Material 
Size 
Cotton 
Color 
Colour Group
```

I selected size and color, and clicked continue, however, there are no associated products. All of the other product data is there.

```
//Mage Product
$mpr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$mpr
    ->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)
    ->setTaxClassId(5)
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
    ->setAttributeSetId(4) // You can determine this another way if you need to.
    ->setSku("C12345")
    ->setName("C12345")
    ->setQty(25)
    ->setShortDescription('short description')
    ->setDescription('description')
    ->setPrice(1)
    ->setStockData(array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'is_salable' => 1,
    ));

    $productData = array(
         '7039604' =>
            array('0' => array('attribute_id' => '85', 'label' => 'ROYAL','value_index' => '28563', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '')
                 ,'1' => array('attribute_id' => '192', 'label' => '14', 'value_index' => '28728', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '')
            )
    );
    $attributeData = array(
        '0' => array(
            'id' => NULL
            ,'label' => 'Color'
            ,'position' => NULL
            ,'values' => array(
                '0' => array('value_index' => 28563, 'label' => 'ROYAL', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '0', 'attribute_id' => '85')
            )
            ,'attribute_id' => 85
            ,'attribute_code' => 'color'
            ,'frontend_label' => 'Color'
            ,'html_id' => 'config_super_product__attribute_0')
        ,'1' => array(
            'id' => NULL
            ,'label' => 'Rivers Size'
            ,'position' => NULL
            ,'values' => array(
                '0' => array('value_index' => 28728, 'label' => '14', 'is_percent' => 0, 'pricing_value' => '0', 'attribute_id' => '192')
            )
            ,'attribute_id' => 192
            ,'attribute_code' => 'rivers_size'
            ,'frontend_label' => 'Rivers Size'
            ,'html_id' => 'config_super_product__attribute_1')
    );
$mpr->setConfigurableProductsData($productData);
$mpr->setConfigurableAttributesData($attributeData);
$mpr->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$mpr->save();
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, you are missing the part where you inform Magento which attributes are used in your configurable (this would correspond to the first step when creating a configurable product in the admin, where you pick the used attributes). Put this before the call to setConfigurableProductsData:

```
$mpr->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(85,192));
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your question? You have to relate simple products to the configurable product.

Go into the backend, create simple products. Choose a size and a color and save the product (after adding all the other things).

Then go to your configurable product, choose the tab "Associated products" and add it there.

Comment: I think the question is about how to programatically create a configurable and associate some simple products to it.

Comment: When I understand him corecct, he expects the simple products to be generated automatically? This is not the case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link to create a configurable product

http://www.codetweet.com/magento/create-configurable-product-magento-programmatically/

**From OP's Comment Below:** The above link shows how to easily add configurable products in Magento step by step. 1) Create simple products, 2) then bind them to add a configurable product.

Comment: You should give more details about the contents found at that url. Single link answers are not really appreciated.

Comment: the above link shows how to easily add configurable procucts in magento step by step.create simple products first then bind them to add a configurable product.

Comment: Thank you Arpit. Single url answers are great when they lead right to the answer. no explanation necessary.